# How to get all users in a site using Content Search WebPart - Office365

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365, managed-property, content-search-web-part

I have to display all users(in a site) in a content search webpart using custom display templates. There was one managed property "SiteMembers" in the search schema, but it's not linked to any crawled properties thus not fetching any values. **Any idea how to get all users in a site in Office365 ?**

Comment: You can look to use Result source which pulls only Users of SharePoint

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it with REST? You can easily get list of users for the site with: `_api/web/siteusers` , then you can format the result however you like.